# List count of occurrences pairs, triplets, etc. from sets

Tags: algorithms, arrays, data-mining

A receipt is an array of products. I have an array of receipts.

I need to generate a report in where I can find the products often bought together.

For instance, for a single receipt where the products bought are `[A, A, B, B, B, C]`, a report would look like

```
Pair - count
A&B - 2
A&A - 1
B&B - 1
A&C - 1
B&C - 1
```

Notice that pair B&A is no longer counted because this is the same as A&B, and similar occurrences. It also has to be sorted by count, decreasing. Also notice that this is just from one receipt rather than multiple, which is what is required.

I also need the algorithm to scale to triples and quadruples, not just pairs.

How would I create an algorithm like this?

There are no set time efficiency constraints. In fact, a more readable solution is preferred over more efficient solutions although efficiency is also appreciated. A python solution is also appreciated, but any language or pseudocode will do.

Comment: If time is not an issue, why not use the naive algorithm ($n^k$ $k$-tuples of $n$ products)? That said, you seem to be looking or some sort of correlation, which is probably standard in data mining and/or machine learning. I expect there to be smarter methods.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like a pretty standard programming exercise, which you don't really need us for. Use hash tables, count stuff, and sort the results.

Comment: Details in the solution for it would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
Use the permutation function and just set the length you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [itemset mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_pattern_mining#Itemset_mining) problem.  Use any [standard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) for that problem.  Follow the links to learn more about standard algorithms for that task.